# Gradle/Grails: Task 'start' not found in project ':client'

Tags: vue.js, grails

I followed the following guide to create a Grails Project with Vue Profile. https://grails-profiles.github.io/vue/latest/guide/

First:
When i run `./gradlew server:bootRun` the process is stuck at 85%, but correctly displays `Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development` and the localhost page is accessible.

Then:
When running `./gradlew client:start`, the build Fails stating:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'start' not found in project ':client'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

The funny thing is it worked before, but as i decided to start over i deleted the project folder and created a new one according to the guide, it wasn't working anymore.

Has anyone experienced a similar error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i run ./gradlew server:bootRun the process is stuck at 85%, but
> correctly displays Grails application running at http://localhost:8080
> in environment: development and the localhost page is accessible.

If you are asking if that indicates something is wrong, it doesn't.  That is expected behavior.  It never gets to 100% because the task is running as long as the app is running.

> Then: When running ./gradlew client:start, the build Fails stating:

That is likely a mistake in the docs.  `./gradlew client:serve` should work.

> Has anyone experienced a similar error?

Likely yes.  We will get the docs updated.

Comment: FYI... The doc error was fixed at https://github.com/grails-profiles/vue/commit/8160d682a42913e322539bc987b210c03788d685 a few months ago and something has failed to publish the update.  We will investigate and fix that.  Thank you for the feedback.